# How to redirect all pages in /directory/ to webpage with htaccess

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect all pages on my site in one directory to a specific page using htaccess.

Example anything like

- `example.com/forums/`
- `example.com/forums/pages`
- `example.com/forums/subdirectory/`
- `example.com/forums/subdirectory/page.html`

basically anything in `/forums/` to only

`example.com/groups/subdirectory/`

It would be a permanent change.  Basically, I bought a new domain from an auction that I migrated my site to and I am getting a lot of 404s from links to whoever was previously on this domain.

Comment: Does your new site have a folder 'forums' as well? That makes a big difference regarding the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, it can be done quite easily like this:

`RedirectMatch /forums/.* https://example.com/groups/subdirectory/`

The dot means 'any character', an asterisk means 'times 0 or any greater number', and the referred-to location must always be written in full.

Comment: You probably mean `RedirectMatch`, instead of `Redirect`. `RedirectMatch` uses regex; `Redirect` uses simple _prefix-matching_. (However, you'd need to modify the _pattern_ to include the start of string anchor and the trailing `.*` is superfluous. The _target URL_ doesn't _need_ to be "written in full", in that it doesn't _need_ to be absolute. It can be a root-relative URL starting with a slash. Although an absolute URL is often recommended.)

Comment: @MrWhite -- It indeed had to be `RedirectMatch`. But, depending on the server, `Redirect` uses more than just simple prefix-matching. Just test this  .htaccess line on a site I created for yourself: `Redirect http.*://gezondezorg.org/behandelkosten.*.php https://gezondezorg.org/vergoedingsregulering.php`. (You'll have to believe me that this is the line.)

Comment: "depending on the server" - in what way does it "depend on the server"? What is that directive supposed to do?

Comment: @MrWhite ~ I did some tests yesterday that made me believe that the same type of regex redirect did work on one site at one host, and not on another site at another host. Checked and rechecked for syntax errors. But I cannot reproduce my findings today. I must have made a mistake. Sorry to waste your time. // Regarding the pattern modification, can you explain that with an example? Were you referring to the prefix matching or the matching in my answer?

Comment: "I must have made a mistake." - You may have been seeing a cached response (a common problem when testing redirects)? The `Redirect` directive in your comment _shouldn't_ have matched anything - hence my puzzlement. (But without knowing the actual URL that is being requested, it's difficult to test.) No worries, thanks for the follow-up. The `Redirect` directive does not support any kind of regex or wildcard syntax. So, characters like `.*` in the URL (first argument) will match a literal dot-asterisk.

Comment: "Regarding the pattern modification" - I was referring to the matching in your answer with `RedirectMatch` (which supports regex). A regex like `/forums/.*` matches "/forums/" _anywhere_ in the URL path, not just at the start of the URL, as in the OPs examples. IF there were other URLs that contained "/forums/" elsewhere in the URL then they would also match and be redirected - this could be undesirable. To ensure the regex only matches URLs that _start with_ `/forums/` (as stated in the question) then you must include the start of string anchor (`^`). ie. `^/forums/.*`.

Comment: However, the trailing `.*` on `^/forums/.*` is also unnecessary (although this is just cosmetic and makes no difference to how it works in this instance). ie. `^/forums/.*` is effectively the same as `^/forums/` here, but a little more "complex". `^/forums/.*` checks for "/forums/" at the start of the URL, followed by any number of any characters. There's no need to check for the "followed by any number of any characters" in this instance - it's just _more work_. So you can simply write this as `^/forums/` and just check for "/forums/" at the start of the URL.

Comment: @MrWhite -- Thanks for the refresher course in regex. // This thread shows how non-intuitive the regex syntax and symbols are. Some six years ago I was the one who debugged a Javascript that (should have) made IE8 support getElementsByClassName, through an improved regex. See http://jsbin.com/zaziz/2/edit?html,output. Now, I hardly remember even the basics of it (while my memory furthermore is fine)....

Answer (score 1):

> I bought a new domain from an auction that I migrated my site to and I am getting a lot of 404s from links to whoever was previously on this domain.

In this case, the 404 response is arguably the *correct* response. Correct for users and search engines. (You could even send a stronger / more deliberate "410 Gone" response - after all, these pages are not coming back it seems.)

A redirect only really makes sense if the content has moved to a different URL, or you have similar/related content at the new URL.

- Redirecting users to a completely different page that is unrelated to the content they are expecting is confusing. And consequently, most users are likely to just "bounce". A better response would be a customised 404 that explains why the page no longer exists and tries to get the users attention in other ways, perhaps suggesting (some of your best) pages on your site that they may find interesting.
- Redirecting search engine bots to a completely different/unrelated page is likely to be seen as a soft-404. But also, redirecting many URLs to a single page is very likely going to be seen as a soft-404.

So, you are not going to gain anything by redirecting in this instance and it could even be a step backwards.